# Wicket 8 DateTextField (from wicket-extension)

Tags: date, wicket, textfield, models

I have a simple Java class, let's name it Person: it contains, as the name suggests, information regarding a person. So it has properties like name, surname, address, sex, phone number and my culprit, the birthday.
I have a page that allows users to edit these fields: it consists of a autocompleting textfield in which users can input the Person ID, or part of it, and choose the Person they want to edit from a drop-down list. The rest of the page is a list of text fields tied with Wicket models to the Person that the users chooses from the list: when this happens, every textfield gets filled correctly with the properties of the Person object chosen. 
Short example of the java representing the textfields and their model:

```
private Person person;
[...]
    formPatient = new Form("patientForm", new PropertyModel<>(this, "person"));
[...]
    formPatient.add(tmp = new MyTextField<>("nome", new PropertyModel<>(this, "person.nome")));
    formPatient.add(tmp = new MyTextField<>("secondoNome", new PropertyModel<>(this, "person.secondoNome")));
    formPatient.add(tmp = new MyTextField<>("cognome", new PropertyModel<>(this, "person.cognome")));
    DropDownChoice sessoDDC = new DropDownChoice("sesso", new PropertyModel<>(this, "person.sesso"), Arrays.asList(Enums.Sex.values()));
    formPatient.add(sessoDDC);
    formPatient.add(dtf = new DateTextField("bday", new PropertyModel<Date>(this, "person.bday"), "dd/MM/yyyy"));
[...]
```

This works fine, as I said. But, for the birthday field, I need to use a text field with a calendar picker. It can be easily arranged, just by changing the related HTML markup from

```
<input style="display: table-cell;" type="text" wicket:id="bday"/>
```

to

```
<input style="display: table-cell;" type="date" wicket:id="bday"/>
```

in order to have a nice and easy-to-use picker to choose the date from.

The problem is that, when the HTML type is set to "date", the auto-updating feature stops working: the DateTextField is always showing the default "dd/MM/yyyy" text, and not a real date. All the other fields still get updated when the user chooses a Person from the list (even the dropdown list representing sex), so the Wicket model mechanism is still working.
I tried overriding methods, both of the PropertyModel and the DateTextField, in order to see if at some point the model object connected to the DateTextField gets lost or something, but it's always there, although it's not represented. I also discovered that the final HTML is like this:

```
<input style="display: table-cell;" type="text" wicket:id="bday" value="01/01/2011" name="bday">
```

so the date information is there, even if the textfield itself seems unable to show it.

Any help is appreciated. If you need more info or more pieces of code, just let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date the value should use `-` as a delimiter between the month, day and year.

Comment: I tried passing as pattern _"dd-MM-yyyy"_ to the DateTextField constructor: the field still shows the default empty value with slashes (_"dd/MM/yyyy"_), but the rendered HTML is _<input style="display: table-cell;" type="date" wicket:id="bday" value="01-01-2011" name="bday">_. Thanks for the tip anyway.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't too clear before. Despite having changed the delimiter to -, the auto-updating function still doesn't work, even if the new pattern seems to be used correctly, as the rendered HTML shows.

Comment: As the link martin-g referred to suggests, try to use the pattern `yyyy-MM-dd`: _"[...] whereas the date value is always formatted yyyy-mm-dd."_

Comment: I do'nt remeber strictly (coding a year ago), seems Wicket date component (with calendar icon) in Polish settings had nuances in keyboard / mouse operation. Keyboard typing had wider "acceptance format range", mouse clicking narrow (or reverse). In general agree with You @martin-g. Best is by documetation

Comment: My bad, didn't notice that the link martin-g suggested inverted the fields order. I just implemented it, and it seems to be working fine. Thanks @Tekki for helping me notice.

Answer (score 3):

I have implemented today a TextField which uses the html5 input type="date" and stores dates in Java 8 [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) - so far it works. Here's the implementation - maybe it will be useful for you:

```
public class Html5LocalDateField extends TextField<LocalDate> {

   public Html5LocalDateField(String id, IModel<LocalDate> model) {
      super(id, model);
      add(AttributeModifier.replace("type", "date"));
   }

   @Override
   public IConverter getConverter(Class type) {
      return new IConverter<LocalDate>() {
         private static final long serialVersionUID = -986861910933163601L;

         @Override
         public LocalDate convertToObject(String value, Locale locale) {
            return LocalDate.parse(value, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE);
         }

         @Override
         public String convertToString(LocalDate date, Locale locale) {
            return date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE);
         }
      };
   }

}
```

Comment: So, I'm guessing that these provides a date picker along with the usual text field?

Comment: Yes. Examples are in the link from martin-g: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date . I thought that was what you were trying to achieve changinginput type `text` to `date`